# JavaScript regex with below rules

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to create a regex for a string with below criteria

**Allowable characters:**

1. uppercase A to Z A-Z
2. lowercase a to z a-z
3. hyphen `
4. apostrophe '
5. single quote '
6. space
7. full stop .
8. numerals 0 to 9 0-9

**Validations:**

1. Must start with an alphabetic character a-zA-Z or apostrophe
2. Cannot have consecutive non-alpha characters except for a full stop followed by a space.

The regex I have from the previous question in this forum. Business came back and want to allow string starting with apostrophe along with [a-zA-Z]. This break some previous validations.
eg: a1rte is valid
'tyer4 is valid
'4rt is invalid

`` ^(?!.*[0-9'`\.\s-]{2})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-`'.\s]+$ ``

Please advise.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. (c)

Comment: Hi Aleksej, why do you imply by that. can regex not solve this issue.

Comment: Regex could solve your problem, for sure. But think about maintainance and changes in the future. Will it be easy to adjust regex to new business requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9`'. -]+$)(?!.*[0-9'` -]{2})[a-zA-Z'][^\r\n.]*(?:\.[ a-z][^\r\n.]*)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `` (?=[a-zA-Z0-9`'. -]+$) `` Assert only allowed characters
- `` (?!.*[0-9'` -]{2}) `` Assert not 2 consecutive listed characters
- `[a-zA-Z']` Match either a char a-zA-Z or apostrophe
- `[^\r\n.]*` Optionally match any char except a newline or a dot
- `(?:\.[ a-z][^\r\n.]*)*` Optionally repeat matching a dot only followed by a space or char a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ilZuhk/1)

Comment: It fails the validation should start with a char [a-zA-Z] or apostrophe.

Comment: @user10118326 I have updated the answer to start with [a-zA-Z] or apostrophe